# DC motor won't spin with PWM unless touched with hand, and other hand touches "ground" from metallic cabinet

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, motor, ground, safety

I'm using the common L298N motor driver module with an Arduino Uno to control one  12V DC motor.
The motor will not spin unless I clutch it in my hand and with another part of my body, touch what I guess is reliable ground. Like a metallic cabinet.

It kind of appears that physical contact with the body of the motor "completes" the circuit because I feel a tingle where my body touches the cabinet.

What are the reasons for such a behavior in DC motors? Does this mean my GND connections are not wired correctly? How do I begin troubleshooting this with a multimeter?

I have tested 2 modules to verify if the module itself was defective but I don't think that's the case.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'd draw a schematic and ensure the 0V between the Uno and the L298 board is connected. You'd then be able to post the schematic where others could look at it.

As for the 'tingle' - how is this powered? By a switchmode supply from the mains?

Assuming you have a valid schematic, you'd then visually check your wiring. Then if there is doubt, use the multimeter to make measurements at various nodes. Measure where? you might ask. That's where a schematic helps us to help you, otherwise we're just waving our hands around some nebulous device.

Your problem is unlikely to be due to the DC motor - more likely a wiring issue.

Comment: Before I draw the schematic, it's worth noting that I did not ground the L298N Module with the Uno GND pin, the driver module is powered by a 12V(measured 12,6V) lead acid battery, and the Uno is powered by USB. I followed this wiring  [from here](https://howtomechatronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Arduino-and-L298N-Circuit-Diagram-DC-Motor-Control.png)

Comment: @RamiRaghfan That's your problem then. You need the devices to share a ground.

Comment: Please check the link after I edited my comment. do you suggest I pull a jumper wire from L298N GND to Arduino GND?

Comment: @RamiRaghfan Put your schematic in the question. We're not going to click a link to a suspicious website.

Comment: I have updated the question. It's a well known website that shares tutorials for arduino. If you hover your mouse over the hyperlink you can "peek" and see that its from How To Electronics, and the hyperlink leads to a .png file.

Comment: 'well known website that shares tutorials for arduino' - that is suspect in itself. The posted schematic is evidence of this.

Comment: Is the schematic bad because of the silly graphics or bad because it's wrong? I'm so sorry I honestly didn't know I shouldn't post links.

Comment: There is no GND wire between the modules! That's a critical omission. The circuit doesn't work on paper and you've proven it doesn't work in reality.

Comment: @Kartman Thank you! I used a jumper wire from GND and touched the GND of the driver module and it worked. I initially thought this was not suitable because I was using 2 power sources, 1 lead-acid battery for the motor and driver, and USB from my PC to the arduino.

Comment: Well, you've proven Kirchoff's law - current flows in a loop.

Comment: Next time I won't blindly trust some website posting long tutorials. I will try to make contact with my previous professors and see if they can help me. You were right, a very suspect site indeed. =)

Comment: Whilst it's easy for me to be critical of these 'tutorial' websites, it is surprisingly difficult to ensure every detail is true and correct, even with a 'simple' circuit - I have co-workers check my documentation and to repeat my procedures to make sure I haven't done or missing anything that is incorrect. Invariably, there'll be one or two things that need attention.

Comment: I just realized that after thinking it over that such a mistake could have been lethal if it was a larger motor with a bigger power supply. Is that right?

Comment: I think it is a bit of a stretch. Your current circuit could be lethal - you have a 12V lead acid battery so what protection do you have with that? If a short occurs, it could burn your house down.